# Angular in VS Code: Is it there any automated way to rename things?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have to refactorize an app written using Angular and I'm finding that renaming components, directives, services, etc. is a pain in the ass in VS Code. Is it there any extension or something to make renaming things easier? What do you do in cases like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renaming components is a pain.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts 
is great,
https://johnpapa.net/refactoring-with-visual-studio-code/
is also a good read.
But honestly I don't really like either, and I often find myself rebuilding the angular app from the start. This way I can also review my code in fine detail when I copy it to my new project and do a once over of anything I might have missed or might need to improve. This is also a good way to check if you really need to use a lot of packages in your package json and a good time to update to the latest angular update if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**MoveTS**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts) VSCode Extension to rename and move TypeScript files/imports.